# Formatting a birthday in years

Tags: datetime, formatting, elixir

```
  def age_post(post) do

    birthday = Timex.date({post.birthday_year, post.birthday_month, post.birthday_day})
    now = Date.now

    years = Timex.diff(now, birthday, :years)

    Integer.to_string(years) <> " ans"

  end
```

I'm quite new with the elixir language, I'm pretty sure you can get the same result than that code in one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cut out some of those intermediate variables using the pipeline operator: `|>`

```clj
def age_post(post) do
  birthday = Timex.date({post.birthday_year, post.birthday_month, post.birthday_day})

  (Date.now |> Timex.diff(birthday, :years) |> Integer.to_string) <> " ans"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to shorten it, I wouldn't know why you couldn't throw everything together:

```
def age_post(post) do
  Integer.to_string(Timex.diff(Date.now, Timex.date({post.birthday_year, post.birthday_month, post.birthday_day}), :years)) <> " ans"
end
```

However, that's absolutely unreadable.

Please re-consider what's really important to you. If this would be code for the company you work for and they'd review your code (and any company-code should be reviewed before being used in production), they wouldn't ask it to be shorter. They'd ask it to be clear.

Comment: well, this code smells imperative code, I'm wondering if it's possible to "translate" that code in functional code.

Comment: @JeremieGes It definitely smells like something, but the original code you posted is by far not the worst way of implementing it. You asked for short, so I helped you out with that. Now it's less repetitive, but harder to maintain. If imperative vs functional is a problem you encounter, feel free to post a new question pointing back to this question with what you really want to improve.

Comment: Can't you just edit your post and add an exemple of what I'm reaching to do with a functional mindset ?

Comment: @JeremieGes Like `|> DateFormat.format!(date, "%a, %d %m %Y %T %Z", :strftime)`?